# When i'm checking if site uploaded complete in webBrowser DocumentCompleted it's all the in Interactive state what else can i do?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

In constructor

```
webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumpage/393");
```

Then in DocumentCompleted

```
void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                return;
            }
            HtmlElementCollection items = this.webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "addMessage")
                {
                   item.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried with the while loop and without.

If without the while loop for some reason it's keep loading the page over and over again every 2-3 seconds.

With the loop i see all the time that the webBrowser2.ReadyState is Interactive all the time.

Also this site is making automatic refresh. But it's never get to the "click"

This is what i see when  i make Inspect Element on the addMessage button:

```
<div id="SecondLineMenu-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 60px;"><div class="SecondLineMenu" id="SecondLineMenu" style="width: 1000px;">
                    <span class="addMessage" onclick="location='http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/393/טבע_ומזג_אוויר/מזג_האוויר'">  | הוספת הודעה</span>
```

I want to click the addMessage button but it's never get there.

I found this working:

```
bool clicked = false;
        private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.webBrowser2.Document != null)
            {
                if (clicked == false)
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
                    foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
                    {
                        if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "addMessage")
                        {
                            item.InvokeMember("click");
                            clicked = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Should i add this as solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool clicked = false;
        private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.webBrowser2.Document != null)
            {
                if (clicked == false)
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
                    foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
                    {
                        if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "addMessage")
                        {
                            item.InvokeMember("click");
                            clicked = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```